# Optimize query with SUM() and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have a given topic and I want to retrieve its similar topics based on topic keywords.

The schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `topic_features` (
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `feature_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `weight` float DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`topic_id`,`feature_id`),
  KEY `feature_id_cover_idx` (`feature_id`,`topic_id`,`weight`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**topic_features** table contains topic keywords and their weights

Given a topic id I follow this scenario :

- I retrive the top 50 keywords of the given topic ordered by weight.
- Then I retrieve all the topics sharing at least one keyword of the
  previous keywords.
- Calculate the similarity between each topic and the given one, based
  on the common keywords between the two topics, the formula is as
  follows :

`SIMILARITY(t,tx) = SUM_FOR_EACH_COMMON_FEATURE(feature_weight(t) *  feature_weight(tx))` where `tx` and `t` share a feature

The query I use currently and which is performming bad is :

```
SELECT
  tf1.topic_id,
  SUM(tf1.weight * tf2.weight) similarity
FROM topic_features tf1
  JOIN
  (
    -- get only top 50 features for the current topic
    SELECT
      feature_id,
      weight
    FROM topic_features
    WHERE topic_id = 124897
    ORDER BY weight DESC
    LIMIT 50
  ) tf2
  USING (feature_id)
 GROUP BY tf1.topic_id
  ORDER BY similarity DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

**Query Explain Plan**

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------+-----------+---------------------------------+

| id | select_type | table               | type | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref            | rows      | Extra                           |

+----+-------------+---------------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------+-----------+---------------------------------+

|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>          | ALL  | NULL                 | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL           |        50 | Using temporary; Using filesort |

|  1 | PRIMARY     | tf1                 | ref  | feature_id_cover_idx | feature_id_cover_idx | 4       | tf2.feature_id |         5 | Using index                     |

|  2 | DERIVED     | topic_features      | ALL  | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY              | 4       |                | 462221416 | Using where; Using filesort     |

+----+-------------+---------------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------+-----------+---------------------------------
```

Is there a way to improve the performance of this query? I was thinking about creating another table which will hold the sum of the weights between each two topics and which will be updated periodically, but I don't know if it is a good idea as I have about 2M topics and 300M topic_features and the update will take a lot of time.

Comment: Add an index on `(topic_id, weight, feature_id)`

Comment: Thanks @ypercubeᵀᴹ, after adding the index the query execution  time was reduced to about 2-3 seconds which is good but still not satistfied, When I checked the execute plan the index works only for the subquery part of the query. Is there a way to optimize the external part?

Comment: You could also replace `SUM(tf1.weight * tf2.weight)` with `tf1.weight * SUM(tf2.weight)` but I doubt you'll see too much of a gain.

Comment: Other than that, it's not much you can do I think. The query should use the 2 composite indexes but it has to do the aggregation and is probably doing that with quite a lot of rows. Playing with buffer sizes might help.